# template choices not showing up in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to Store the "gender" and "likes_cheeese" fields information in my models but I it seems that the both the values is not getting stored in the database and hence not displaying in admin.
any suggestion to make it work and show in database?

views.py

```html
@login_required(login_url='/users/login/')
def account(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            import ipdb
            ipdb.set_trace()
            full_name = request.POST.get('name')
            likes_cheese = request.POST.get('like')
            profile_picture = request.POST.get('profile_picture')
            sex = request.POST.get('sex')

            user_info = request.user.id
            user_info = User.objects.get(id=user_info)

            try:
                user_info_collect = UserProfileInfo.objects.get(user=user_info)
                user_info_collect.full_name = full_name
                user_info_collect.likes_cheese = likes_cheese
                user_info_collect.sex = sex

            except UserProfileInfo.DoesNotExist:
                user_info_collect = UserProfileInfo(
                    user=user_info,
                    full_name=full_name,
                    likes_cheese=likes_cheese,
                    profile_picture=profile_picture,
                    gender=sex)

            user_info_collect.save()
            context = {'success': True, 'message': 'Successfully saved'}
            context.update(csrf(request))
            return render_to_response('users/account.html', context)

        except:
            context = {'success': False, 'message': 'Saving failed'}

    else:
        context.update(csrf(request))
        return render_to_response('users/account.html', context)
```

MODELS

```html
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
Boolean_YES_NO_CHOICES = ((None, 'Others'), (True, 'Male'), (False, 'Female'))
GENDER_CHOICES = (('', 'Others'), ('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'))


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        verbose_name='Name')

    email = models.EmailField(
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        verbose_name='Email')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='Female')

    likes_cheese = models.NullBooleanField(
        choices=Boolean_YES_NO_CHOICES,
        max_length=3,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,)

    full_name = models.CharField(
        default='',
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        null=True)

    profile_picture = models.ImageField(
        default='',
        upload_to='media/Users/',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Profile Picture',
        help_text='Apna photo dal chutiye.')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

HTML

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <p>
        <h1>Here's what we know about you!</h1>
        <strong>Name - </strong>{{account.full_name}}
        <strong>Like Cheese - </strong>{{account.likes_cheese}}
    </p>
    <p>
        <form action="/users/account/" method="POST" name="user_account">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <label>Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" >

            <select name="sex">
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
            </select>

            <label>Profile Picture</label>
            <input type="file" name="profile_picture">

            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Save'>
        </form>
    </p>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I have checked using ipdb, my html returns correct values i.e.  'Male' or 'Female'.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @Mohit You should share you code, so it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Hi, I have inserted my code as well in my question. Please see if you can help me out in this.